# Android c2dm "Unknown permission" on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I tested my GCM code in couple of android devices on various versions. It seemed to work fine most of the Android devices, but specific to Samsung Galaxy Tab, I m getting the below exception whenever I try to connect to my cloud server.  I am running out of ideas why only on Samsung Galaxy Tab.. I tested on Galaxy S4, S1 and 2.3 devices and it worked fine.

Any thoughts? I shared the Manifest also for your reference.

```
**06-30 16:47:35.768: I/ActivityManager(650): Force stopping package com.lakshmi.sharemessages appid=10067 user=-1
06-30 16:47:37.024: D/PackageManager(650): New package installed in /data/app/com.lakshmi.sharemessages-1.apk**
06-30 16:47:37.103: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
06-30 16:47:37.143: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
06-30 16:47:37.204: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
06-30 16:47:37.204: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
06-30 16:47:37.214: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
06-30 16:47:37.244: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
06-30 16:47:37.264: W/PackageManager(650): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x89be45)
06-30 16:47:37.283: W/PackageManager(650): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
06-30 16:47:37.343: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
06-30 16:47:37.394: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT in package com.android.exchange
06-30 16:47:37.394: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER in package com.android.exchange
06-30 16:47:37.404: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER in package com.android.exchange
06-30 16:47:37.524: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
06-30 16:47:37.524: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
06-30 16:47:37.524: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
06-30 16:47:37.534: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
06-30 16:47:37.544: W/PackageManager(650): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x88be45)
***06-30 16:47:37.594: W/PackageManager(650): Unknown permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE in package com.lakshmi.sharemessages***
06-30 16:47:38.994: I/InputReader(650): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-30 16:47:40.017: W/AccountTypeManager(949): No authenticator found for type=com.android.exchange, ignoring it.
06-30 16:47:40.037: I/AccountTypeManager(949): Loaded meta-data for 0 account types, 0 accounts in 212ms(wall) 7ms(cpu)
06-30 16:47:40.114: I/ActivityManager(650): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=1297 uid=10023 gids={50023, 1015, 1028}
06-30 16:47:40.534: D/ExchangeService(1062): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-30 16:47:41.294: D/dalvikvm(650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 783K, 23% free 6013K/7796K, paused 503ms+119ms, total 1659ms
06-30 16:47:41.314: W/ActivityManager(650): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-30 16:47:41.434: E/Trace(1297): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-30 16:47:41.694: D/ExchangeService(1062): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-30 16:47:41.794: E/ActivityThread(1062): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf22d0 that was originally bound here
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lakshmi.sharemessages"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.lakshmi.sharemessages.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lakshmi.sharemessages.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: any luck.. even i am facing similar issues.